# Heroku for Real-Time game server

Tags: facebook, flash, heroku, real-time

I have little experience using Heroku.

I wanted to get my multiplayer (realtime interactive) flash game up on facebook and ran into some https issue.  After hours of trying to find a solution that didn't require hundreds of dollars to purchase and figure out ssl certs, I discovered the option of linking my facebook app through Heroku.

Basically i've been using Heroku as a webserver with the client that connects to the remote game server.

I see a ton of add-ons, dynos, and all sorts of options with Heroku.

The game server is coded in VB.NET. Is there any possible way of getting it hosted on Heroku? (maybe an add-on?)

Also, I have had a hard time finding simplified information on Heroku (Heroku for dummies type style lol). Any links for simplified sources would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why Heroku for SSL?**

Purchasing a DV (domain validated) SSL certificate can be [less than 10 USD per year](http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl-certificate.aspx). Why spending 20 USD per month for the Heroku SSL Addon?

---

**.NET application on Heroku**

As heroku is running linux (Ubuntu 10.04 according to [this official article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack)), you may try to run your .NET application with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). ([Mono VB.NET support](http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support))

You may want to read:

- [How to Deploy a .NET App with Mono on Heroku](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2012/01/how-to-deploy-mono-projects-to-heroku.html)
- [YouTube - How to Deploy a .NET App with Mono on Heroku](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkdiTzgqqsk)

hope this helps.